# POST http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth 403 (Forbidden) / for customer service chat where i only need auth for admins

Tags: laravel, authentication, chat, broadcast

How can I use broadcasting/auth for the admin but not for the normal user, and still both can chat with each other?

// BroadcastServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{

    Broadcast::routes();

    require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

// Channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
return (int) $user->id === (int) $id; });

Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
return $user;  });
```

// MessageSent Event

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PresenceChannel('chat');
}
```

I'm getting this error: POST http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth 403 (Forbidden), but when i remove from laravel echo (Echo.join('chat')) the error goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve such thing using `Middleware` in laravel.

This quote is from laravel's official website:

> Middleware provide a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests
>   entering your application. For example, Laravel includes a middleware
>   that verifies the user of your application is authenticated. If the
>   user is not authenticated, the middleware will redirect the user to
>   the login screen. However, if the user is authenticated, the
>   middleware will allow the request to proceed further into the
>   application.

Complete reading from this [website](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware)

Comment: Thanks! after reading from the website i was able to find something similar to my question using the middleware